# Change Arithmetic Right Shift to Logical Right Shift

Tags: c, integer, bitwise

The following code is a solution to a textbook ([Bryant&O'Hallaron: Computer Systems A programmer's Perspective 2nd Ed](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/2e/home.html)) problem in bit-level data manipulation (attempted for the challenge, not a class).  The function `srl` is not written necessarily in a practical manner, but within the constraints required by the problem.  The task is to convert the result of an arithmetic right shift to what would be the result of a logical right shift.

### Questions

Is there is a clearer, more straight-forward way to write this **within the required constraints of the problem** (perhaps with fewer `~` operations)?

There is a need to avoid undefined behavior of the left shift, when `k = 0`.  In this case `int_bits - k = int_bits`, which causes the shift to work unpredictably.  Is there a better way to handle the undefined behavior of the shift operations, when the shift is larger than the number of bits in the interger?

It seems to work correctly, but I lack an answer, so any feedback on the solution would be appreciated.

### Requirements

- No additional right shifts or type casts may be used beyond the given expression

  ```
    /*Perform shift arithmetically*/
     unsigned xsra = (int) x >> k;
  ```
- Only addition or subtraction may be used, no multiplication, division, or modulus
- No comparison operators and no conditionals
- Only bit-wise operations (except further right shifts) and logical operators may be used

### Code

```
unsigned srl(unsigned x, int k) {
    /*Perform shift arithmetically*/
    unsigned xsra = (int) x >> k;

    unsigned int_bits = sizeof(int) << 3;//calculates the number of bits in int (assumes 8-bit byte)

    unsigned zero_or_all_bits = ~0 + !k;//for k = 0, corrects for the undefined behavior in
                                        //the left shift produced from int_bits - k = int_bits
                                        //if k != 0, !k == 0, and zero_or_all_bits == ~0
                                        //if k == 0, zero_or_all_bits == 0

    unsigned high_bit_mask = ~(zero_or_all_bits << (zero_or_all_bits & (int_bits - k)));
    /******************************************/
    //creates a mask of either all bits set in an unsigned int (UINT_MAX)
    //or a mask with k high bits cleared.
    //if k == 0, then high_bit_mask = ~(0 << 0) = ~0.
    //if k != 0, then high_bit_mask = ~(~0 << (~0 & (int_bits - k)))
    //ex. k == 3, high_bit_mask == 0x1FFFFFFF
    //ex. k == 0, high_bit_mask == 0xFFFFFFFF
    //ex. k == 31, high_bit_mask == 0xFFFFFFFE
    /******************************************/

    return xsra & high_bit_mask;
}
```

---

### Test Code

```
printf("Test srl:\n");
printf("srl(-1, 1): 0x%.8x\n", srl(-1, 1));
printf("srl(-1, 4): 0x%.8x\n", srl(-1, 4));
printf("srl(-1, 5): 0x%.8x\n", srl(-1, 5));
printf("srl(-1, 31): 0x%.8x\n", srl(-1, 31));
printf("srl(-1, 0): 0x%.8x\n", srl(-1, 0));

printf("srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 1): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 1));
printf("srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 4): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 4));
printf("srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 5): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 5));
printf("srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 31): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 31));
printf("srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 0): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 0));

printf("srl(0x80000000, 1): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x80000000, 1));
printf("srl(0x80000000, 4): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x80000000, 4));
printf("srl(0x80000000, 5): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x80000000, 5));
printf("srl(0x80000000, 31): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x80000000, 31));
printf("srl(0x80000000, 0): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0x80000000, 0));

printf("srl(0, 1): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0, 1));
printf("srl(0, 4): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0, 4));
printf("srl(0, 5): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0, 5));
printf("srl(0, 31): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0, 31));
printf("srl(0, 0): 0x%.8x\n", srl(0, 0));

printf("srl(1, 1): 0x%.8x\n", srl(1, 1));
printf("srl(1, 4): 0x%.8x\n", srl(1, 4));
printf("srl(1, 5): 0x%.8x\n", srl(1, 5));
printf("srl(1, 31): 0x%.8x\n", srl(1, 31));
printf("srl(1, 0): 0x%.8x\n", srl(1, 0));
```

---

### Output

```
Test srl:     
srl(-1, 1): 0x7fffffff     
srl(-1, 4): 0x0fffffff     
srl(-1, 5): 0x07ffffff     
srl(-1, 31): 0x00000001     
srl(-1, 0): 0xffffffff     
srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 1): 0x3fffffff     
srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 4): 0x07ffffff     
srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 5): 0x03ffffff     
srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 31): 0x00000000     
srl(0x7FFFFFFF, 0): 0x7fffffff     
srl(0x80000000, 1): 0x40000000     
srl(0x80000000, 4): 0x08000000     
srl(0x80000000, 5): 0x04000000     
srl(0x80000000, 31): 0x00000001     
srl(0x80000000, 0): 0x80000000     
srl(0, 1): 0x00000000     
srl(0, 4): 0x00000000     
srl(0, 5): 0x00000000     
srl(0, 31): 0x00000000     
srl(0, 0): 0x00000000     
srl(1, 1): 0x00000000     
srl(1, 4): 0x00000000     
srl(1, 5): 0x00000000     
srl(1, 31): 0x00000000     
srl(1, 0): 0x00000001
```

Comment: @Reinderien  Thanks for the edit.  How do you get the closing brace "}" in the code section?  It always drops out on me.

Comment: Make sure that it's 4-tabbed in.

Comment: Code is to do a "Logical Right Shift" yet is is called `srl()`.  What does _srl_ mean?  Shift-Right-Logical?  That 'l' is easier to see as implying _left_.

Comment: @chux that was what the problem called it. I could have changed it to make it clearer, but did not bother.

Comment: @chux I did the change from logical to arithmetic last night with same requirements. The book called it sra. Real descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Regarding all the implementation-defined behavior present:

  - In the general case, it is implementation-defined if right-shifting a negative number results in arithmetic shift or logical shift. It is up to the compiler to pick.
  - In your specific case, you go from `unsigned`x type to signed type `(int)x`. You have implicit, implementation-defined conversions from signed type to unsigned type and back. The program is allowed to raise a signal when going from a large `unsigned int` to `int`. So it is not a good idea, but no way around it as your program is written.
  - Meaning, at the point when we have executed the first line of your function, we have no idea of the state of the variable or the program as whole. On a specific system, it's another story, but your question is about generic C.
- `sizeof(int) << 3`. Replacing multiplication by 8 with shifts manually is bad practice, known as "pre-mature optimization". Never do this, let the compiler handle it. Correct code should be `8 * sizeof(int)` or `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`.
- Regarding `~0 + !k`. If k is 0, the result is `-1 + 1` = 0, assuming two's complement. Otherwise, if k is not 0, the result is `-1`, which you then implicitly convert to unsigned type. What's the reason for writing such obfuscated code, are you trying to make the code more branch-friendly or something? Don't do that before you have found a bottleneck during benchmarking. Instead write:

  ```
  if(k==0)
  {
    zero_or_all_bits = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    zero_or_all_bits = ~0u;
  }
  ```

or if you prefer, `unsigned int zero_or_all_bits = (k==0) ? 0u : ~0u`.

---

As for how to convert the result of an arithmetic shift to a logical, without any questionable conversions or UB hiccups, simply do:

```
int val = x >> y;                // some manner of arithmetic shift
...
const size_t int_bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
unsigned int mask = (1u << y)-1; // create a mask corresponding to the number of shifts
mask = mask << (int_bits-y);     // shift the mask in place from MSB and down
mask = ~mask;                    // then invert the whole integer, making mask bits zero, rest ones
val = val & mask;                // set the bits to zero
```

That is, simply clear the bits which were set by arithmetic shift. This code was intentionally written in several steps to make it easier to understand.

For example, given `x = -8` and `y = 2`:

- `x = -8` is `0xFFFFFFF8` hex (2's complement).
- `-8 >> 2` arithmetic shift gives `0xFFFFFFFE`. Two zeroes getting shifted out, two ones shifted in.
- The corresponding logical shift would be `0x3FFFFFFE`. Two zeroes getting shifted out, two zeroes shifted in.
- `(1u << 2)` gives 0x4. `(1u << 2)-1` gives 0x3, a mask of ones 2 bits wide.
- Shift the mask 0x3 in place, 32-2=30 bits to the left. Temporary value `0xC0000000`.
- Invert this, we get `0x3FFFFFFF` which is the desired mask.
- Data AND mask gives: `0xFFFFFFFE` AND `0x3FFFFFFF` = `0x3FFFFFFE`.

Comment: @RJM Uh, sorry, that was posted in a hurry. Of course you'll want a generic case, not sure what I was thinking. I have updated the answer with a generic C code and an example, hope it is clearer.

Comment: @RJM As for UB, it doesn't apply unless we left shift a signed `int` with negative value, or in case we left shift data into the sign bit of a signed `int`. Which we avoid entirely by using `unsigned int`.

Comment: So, when I was getting a zero left shift when int_bits - k == 32, ex 0xFFFFFFFF << 32 == 0xFFFFFFFF, there must have been an implicit cast to make 0xFFFFFFFF signed?

Comment: Sorry to belabor this, but wouldn't (1u << y)-1; require an implicit cast of (1u << y) to int?

Comment: Suggest `~u` --> `~0u`

Comment: @RJM It's the type used that determines undefined behavior, not the raw binary representation. If you store `0xFFFFFFFF` (-1) in an `int` and left shift, you get undefined behavior. If you store the same in an `unsigned int` and shift, it is well-defined. The C standard C17 6.5.7 is quite easy to read here: "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions" ... "If E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @RJM `(1u << y)-1` evaluates the shift based on the type of the left operand. The result of the shift operators always have the type of the left operand (special case for shifts specifically). `1u` has type `unsigned int` and so does the result. Then the result - 1 is evaluated. The rule called _the usual arithmetic conversions_ ("type balancing") applies, the signed operand `1` is converted to unsigned, since the other operand is unsigned. More info: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Comment: @RJM Also, mind the terms _cast_ and _conversion_. A conversion is when an operand changes type, either implicitly or explicitly. A cast is when the programmer explicitly enforces a conversion with the cast `()` operator.

Comment: @Lundin Excellent.  Thanks Lundin.  Other than StackExchange, do you have a recommendation for where I can read more about this stuff?  Something more consolidated?

Answer (score 2):

LGTM.

One recommendation is to split `unsigned zero_or_all_bits = ~0 + !k;` into two lines, like

```
    unsigned zero_or_all_bits = ~0;

    // for k = 0, corrects for the undefined behavior in
    // the left shift produced from int_bits - k = int_bits
    // if k != 0, !k == 0, and zero_or_all_bits == ~0
    // if k == 0, zero_or_all_bits == 0

    zero_or_all_bits += !k;
```

Two other comments (`// calculates` and `// creates mask`) add no value. I recommend to remove them.

Comment: Thank you. I have never posted a question, so I figured I'd over comment.

Comment: Good suggestion. The question said to write clear, understandable code. I found that difficult here.

Comment: `~0` will not provide an all ones pattern to `unsigned` here on now rare non-2's complement machines.  Best to use `~0u` or `-1u`.

Comment: @chux Actually, I did not state it in my post, but the problem said to assume two's complement.

Comment: @chux The ~ operator (as well as `| & ^`) doesn't care about the signedness format. ~ simply performs a bitwise complement of all bits. Not to be confused with 1's and 2's complement. It is however good practice to avoid signed integer constants when dealing with bitwise arithmetic, so `0u` is good practice still.

Comment: @Lundin It is not the `~0` will not make an all ones pattern for as you say it is a bitwise complement of all bits.  It is the _assignment_ of that `int `values to an `unsigned` which can change the pattern. e.g. [`~0` --> `-0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) --> `0u`